# Responsive Table plugin with coulmn Swapping & Column Priority

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need plugin like [table-saw](http://filamentgroup.github.io/tablesaw/demo/toggle.html) with column swapping functionality with different views, currently working on updating table-saw methods, but looking for some simple plugin based solution.

Regards,
   Sopo

Comment: hide and show doesn't change its column series, i want that thing with this

Answer (score 0):

You should go with datatables
http://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/

Comment: I dont want drag and drop functionality for it, i'll check whether it is having views based auto column update functionality. thanks